# How to call controller in codeigniter from folder?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a website with

- **frontend**:  wordpress
- **backend** :  codeigniter

Codeigniter instance is saved in folder named as **backend**.

*Setting up a test environment of backend as.*

- **folder name**:  team
- **codeigniter is install in:**   abc folder

So the path will be as:

> publichtml/team/abc

Now Trying to sign in there is a **404 not found error**.

can any one help me whats going wrong in script:

```
<script> 
function sendData() {
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var userpass = $("#userpass").val();

    $.post('https://example.com/team/abc/index.php/login/authenticateUserWeb',{ 'username': username, 'userpass': userpass }, function( data ) {

  alert(data);   
    if(data == 'success'){
      window.location = "https://example.com/team/abc/index.php/companyadmin/folders";

    }else if(data == 'successuser'){
      window.location = "https://example.com/team/abc/index.php/companyuser";  
    }else if(data == 'expired'){
      window.location = 'https://example.com/team/abc/index.php/companyadmin/selectPacakge';    

    }else{
            $("#user").html(data);
            //alert(data);
        }

});

    }
```

now when i am trying to sign in finding below error in console log:

POST https://example.com/team/abc/index.php/login/authenticateUserWeb

> 301 Moved Permanently

`jquery-1.10.2.js (line 6)`
GET https://example.com/team/abc/login/authenticateUserWeb

> 404 Not Found

https://example.com/team/abc/login/authenticateUserWeb"

> NetworkError: 404 Not Found

Comment: don't know but I notice that index.php has been removed from https://example.com/team/abc/index.php/login/authenticateUserWeb      and url is changes like GET https://example.com/team/abc/login/authenticateUserWeb

Comment: here is my config file: $config['base_url'] = "https://example.com/team/abc/";   $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';$config['allow_get_array']  = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger']  = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';

Comment: I think the problem is with HTACCESS

Comment: your required to allow backend folder to have access in wordpress htaccess, it is done by ReWrite Cond in htaccess

Comment: You are right @markin Bhatt. Can you suggest me that how can I setup .htaccess cond to access backend folder?

Comment: hello @MarmikBhatt could you help me to short out this problem?

Comment: I need to see directory structure, but you can use this as reference...http://www.htaccess-guide.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to add 2 project one with wordpress and other in codeigniter

**Assume below directory structure**

```
www/
    .htaccess (wordpress htaccess)
    index.php (wordpress index.php and files)
www/backend/
    .htaccess (codeigniter htaccess)
    index.php (codeigniter htaccess)
```

**For HTACCESS file for wordpress**

```
//just add this line in wordpress htaccess
<Directory "backend/">
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**For Codeigniter HTACCESS file**

```
//add this lines in your codeigniter htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /backend/
...
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /backend/index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

This type of has work everytime for me...

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, but to me it seems that your 'index.php' is missing from the url:

```
https://example.com/team/abc/index.php/login/authenticateUserWeb
```

can be found while:

```
https://example.com/team/abc/login/authenticateUserWeb
```

cannot (returns 404).

The difference between these url's is that there is no /index.php/ in the last one.

Some steps you can check:

- Is your Codeigniter config.php adapted to the new location of your test backend? (base_url).
- It seems that you are using index.php in url's so you are NOT using a rewriting of the url to work without index.php. If this is the case make sure that the 'index_page' setting in your config.php is correct (the value:'index.php' probably suffices) and not empty.

Comment: here is my config file: $config['base_url'] = "example.com/team/abc/";; $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE; $config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE; $config['controller_trigger'] = 'c'; $config['function_trigger'] = 'm'; $config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';

Comment: Do you have an .htaccess file in your Codeigniter folder to rewrite urls with 'index.php' to have 'index.php' removed from the url?
If so make the value in $config['index_page'] an empty string.

Comment: not in codeigniter folder but i have .htaccess file in wordpress

Comment: I can't test it but try adding
    RewriteRule ^team/abc/.*$ - [L]
after RewriteBase /